# How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip-address

I need to somehow retrieve the client's IP address using JavaScript; no server side code, not even SSI.

However, I'm not against using a free 3rd party script/service.

Answer (score 1145):

I would use a web service that can return JSON (along with jQuery to make things simpler). Below are all the *active* free IP lookup services I could find and the information they return. If you know of others, then please add a comment and I'll update this answer.

---

### [Abstract](https://www.abstractapi.com/ip-geolocation-api)

```js
let apiKey = '1be9a6884abd4c3ea143b59ca317c6b2';
$.getJSON('https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 10,000 requests per month
- Requires registration to get your API key

---

### [BigDataCloud](https://www.bigdatacloud.com/ip-geolocation-apis)

```js
// Base
let apiKey = 'd9e53816d07345139c58d0ea733e3870';
$.getJSON('https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/ip-geolocation?key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// Base + Confidence Area
let apiKey = 'd9e53816d07345139c58d0ea733e3870';
$.getJSON('https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/ip-geolocation-with-confidence?key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// Base + Confidence Area + Hazard Report
let apiKey = 'd9e53816d07345139c58d0ea733e3870';
$.getJSON('https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/ip-geolocation-full?key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 10,000 requests per month
- Requires registration to get your API key

---

### [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

```js
$.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace', function(data) {
  // Convert key-value pairs to JSON
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39284735/452587
  data = data.trim().split('\n').reduce(function(obj, pair) {
    pair = pair.split('=');
    return obj[pair[0]] = pair[1], obj;
  }, {});
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- Returns plain text
- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [DB-IP](https://db-ip.com/)

**Try it:** https://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self

```
$.getJSON('https://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "ipAddress": "116.12.250.1",
  "continentCode": "AS",
  "continentName": "Asia",
  "countryCode": "SG",
  "countryName": "Singapore",
  "city": "Singapore (Queenstown Estate)"
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 1,000 requests per day
- Requires non-null `Origin` request header

---

### [Geobytes](https://geobytes.com/)

**Try it:** http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails

```
$.getJSON('http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "geobytesforwarderfor": "",
  "geobytesremoteip": "116.12.250.1",
  "geobytesipaddress": "116.12.250.1",
  "geobytescertainty": "99",
  "geobytesinternet": "SA",
  "geobytescountry": "Saudi Arabia",
  "geobytesregionlocationcode": "SASH",
  "geobytesregion": "Ash Sharqiyah",
  "geobytescode": "SH",
  "geobyteslocationcode": "SASHJUBA",
  "geobytescity": "Jubail",
  "geobytescityid": "13793",
  "geobytesfqcn": "Jubail, SH, Saudi Arabia",
  "geobyteslatitude": "27.004999",
  "geobyteslongitude": "49.660999",
  "geobytescapital": "Riyadh ",
  "geobytestimezone": "+03:00",
  "geobytesnationalitysingular": "Saudi Arabian ",
  "geobytespopulation": "22757092",
  "geobytesnationalityplural": "Saudis",
  "geobytesmapreference": "Middle East ",
  "geobytescurrency": "Saudi Riyal",
  "geobytescurrencycode": "SAR",
  "geobytestitle": "Saudi Arabia"
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 16,384 requests per hour
- No SSL (https) with the free plan
- Can return the wrong location

---

### [GeoIPLookup.io](https://geoiplookup.io/api)

```js
$.getJSON('https://json.geoiplookup.io/?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 10,000 requests per hour
- Free plan only for non-commercial use
- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [geoPlugin](https://www.geoplugin.com/)

**Try it:** http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp

```
$.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "geoplugin_request": "116.12.250.1",
  "geoplugin_status": 200,
  "geoplugin_credit": "Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href=\\'http://www.maxmind.com\\'>http://www.maxmind.com</a>.",
  "geoplugin_city": "Singapore",
  "geoplugin_region": "Singapore (general)",
  "geoplugin_areaCode": "0",
  "geoplugin_dmaCode": "0",
  "geoplugin_countryCode": "SG",
  "geoplugin_countryName": "Singapore",
  "geoplugin_continentCode": "AS",
  "geoplugin_latitude": "1.2931",
  "geoplugin_longitude": "103.855797",
  "geoplugin_regionCode": "00",
  "geoplugin_regionName": "Singapore (general)",
  "geoplugin_currencyCode": "SGD",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol": "&#36;",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8": "$",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter": 1.4239
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 120 requests per minute
- No SSL (https) with the free plan

---

### [Hacker Target](https://hackertarget.com/geoip-ip-location-lookup/)

```js
$.get('https://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q=116.12.250.1', function(data) {
  // Convert key-value pairs to JSON
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39284735/452587
  data = data.trim().split('\n').reduce(function(obj, pair) {
    pair = pair.split(': ');
    return obj[pair[0]] = pair[1], obj;
  }, {});
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 100 requests per day
- Requires IP address parameter
- Returns plain text

---

### [ipapi](https://ipapi.co/)

**Try it:** https://ipapi.co/json/

```
$.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json/', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "ip": "116.12.250.1",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "region": "Central Singapore Community Development Council",
  "country": "SG",
  "country_name": "Singapore",
  "postal": null,
  "latitude": 1.2855,
  "longitude": 103.8565,
  "timezone": "Asia/Singapore"
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 1,000 requests per day
- Requires SSL (https)
- Requires non-null `Origin` request header
- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [IP-API](https://ip-api.com/)

**Try it:** http://ip-api.com/json

```
$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "as": "AS3758 SingNet",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "country": "Singapore",
  "countryCode": "SG",
  "isp": "SingNet Pte Ltd",
  "lat": 1.2931,
  "lon": 103.8558,
  "org": "Singapore Telecommunications",
  "query": "116.12.250.1",
  "region": "01",
  "regionName": "Central Singapore Community Development Council",
  "status": "success",
  "timezone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "zip": ""
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 150 requests per minute
- No SSL (https) with the free plan

---

### [ipdata](https://ipdata.co/)

```js
let apiKey = 'be0f755b93290b4c100445d77533d291763a417c75524e95e07819ad';
$.getJSON('https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 1,500 requests per day
- Requires registration to get your API key
- Requires SSL (https)

---

### [IP Find](https://ipfind.co/)

```js
let apiKey = '50e887ce-e3bb-4f00-a9b9-667597db5539';
$.getJSON('https://ipfind.co/me?auth=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 300 requests per day
- Requires registration to get your API key

---

### [ipgeolocation](https://ipgeolocation.io/)

```js
let apiKey = 'f8e0b361e8f4405c94613ab534959fdf';
$.getJSON('https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 50,000 requests per month
- Requires registration to get your API key
- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/)

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- None

---

### [IPInfoDB](https://ipinfodb.com/)

```js
let apiKey = '25864308b6a77fd90f8bf04b3021a48c1f2fb302a676dd3809054bc1b07f5b42';
$.getJSON('https://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?format=json&key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- Two requests per second
- Requires registration to get your API key

---

### [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/)

```js
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 50,000 requests per month

---

### [ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co/)

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- Free plan includes 100,000 requests
- Requires registration to get your API key
- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [ipstack](https://ipstack.com/) (formerly freegeoip.net)

**Try it:** [http://api.ipstack.com/*<ip_address>*?access_key=*<your_api_key>*](http://api.ipstack.com/116.12.250.1?access_key=7d558868069cc34f545d822af056be3c)

```
$.getJSON('http://api.ipstack.com/<ip_address>?access_key=<your_api_key>', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "ip": "116.12.250.1",
  "type": "ipv4",
  "continent_code": "AS",
  "continent_name": "Asia",
  "country_code": "SG",
  "country_name": "Singapore",
  "region_code": "01",
  "region_name": "Central Singapore Community Development Council",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "zip": null,
  "latitude": 1.2931,
  "longitude": 103.8558,
  "location": {
    "geoname_id": 1880252,
    "capital": "Singapore",
    "languages": [
      {
        "code": "en",
        "name": "English",
        "native": "English"
      },
      {
        "code": "ms",
        "name": "Malay",
        "native": "Bahasa Melayu"
      },
      {
        "code": "ta",
        "name": "Tamil",
        "native": "தமிழ்"
      },
      {
        "code": "zh",
        "name": "Chinese",
        "native": "中文"
      }
    ],
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/sg.svg",
    "country_flag_emoji": "",
    "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1F8 U+1F1EC",
    "calling_code": "65",
    "is_eu": false
  }
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 10,000 requests per month
- Requires IP address parameter
- Requires registration to get your API key
- No SSL (https) with the free plan

---

### [jsonip.com](https://getjsonip.com/)

```js
$.getJSON('https://jsonip.com/', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [JSON Test](https://www.jsontest.com/)

**Try it:** http://ip.jsontest.com/

```
$.getJSON('http://ip.jsontest.com/', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "ip": "116.12.250.1"
}
```

**Limitations:**

- No SSL (https)
- Returns only IPv6 address if you have that

---

### [Snoopi.io](https://www.snoopi.io/)

```js
let apiKey = 'ed5ebbeba257b8f262a6a9bbc0ec678e';
$.getJSON('https://api.snoopi.io/116.12.250.1?apikey=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Limitations:**

- 10,000 requests per month
- 1 request every 2 seconds
- Requires IP address parameter
- Requires registration to get your API key

---

#### VANILLA JAVASCRIPT

With modern browsers, you can use the native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of relying on jQuery's `$.getJSON()`. Here's an example:

```js
let apiKey = '1be9a6884abd4c3ea143b59ca317c6b2';
// Make the request
fetch('https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=' + apiKey)
  // Extract JSON body content from HTTP response
  .then(response => response.json())
  // Do something with the JSON data
  .then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  });
```

#### NOTES

- Since these are all free services, who knows when/if they will be taken offline down the road (exhibit A: [Telize](https://www.telize.com/)).
- Most of these services also offer a paid tier in case you want more features and stability.
- As @skobaljic noted in the comments below, the request quotas are mostly academic since calls are happening client-side and most end users will never exceed their quota.
- Some services don't have runnable snippets because they don't allow SSL connections in the free plan or require a non-null `Origin` request header (StackOverflow snippets are forced to use https and have `Origin: null` in the request headers).

#### UPDATES

- 2/1/2016: Removed [Telize](https://www.telize.com/) (no longer offers free plan)
- 4/18/2016: Removed [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/) (out of service)
- 4/26/2016: Added [DB-IP](https://db-ip.com/)
- 4/26/2016: Added [Hacker Target](https://hackertarget.com/geoip-ip-location-lookup/)
- 7/6/2016: Reinstated [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/)
- 7/6/2016: Removed [ip-json.rhcloud.com](http://ip-json.rhcloud.com/) (dead link)
- 12/21/2016: Removed [Hacker Target](https://hackertarget.com/geoip-ip-location-lookup/) (out of service)
- 2/10/2017: Added [Nekudo](http://geoip.nekudo.com/)
- 4/20/2017: Added [ipapi](https://ipapi.co/) (thanks Ahmad Awais)
- 4/24/2017: Reinstated [Hacker Target](https://hackertarget.com/geoip-ip-location-lookup/)
- 4/24/2017: Removed [Snoopi.io](https://www.snoopi.io/) (out of service)
- 7/16/2017: Added limitation "No SSL (https) with the free plan"
- 7/16/2017: Added [IP Find](https://ipfind.co/) (thanks JordanC)
- 9/25/2017: Added [Stupid Web Tools](http://www.stupidwebtools.com/) (thanks Cœur)
- 3/16/2018: Added [ipdata](https://ipdata.co/) (thanks Jonathan)
- 4/14/2018: Renamed freegeoip.net to [ipstack](https://ipstack.com/) (thanks MA-Maddin)
- 4/16/2018: Added [GeoIPLookup.io](https://geoiplookup.io/) (thanks Rob Waa)
- 6/11/2018: Added [ipgeolocation](https://ipgeolocation.io/) (thanks Ejaz Ahmed)
- 7/31/2019: Added [ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co/) (thanks Laurent)
- 8/16/2019: Added [SmartIP.io](https://smartip.io/) (thanks kevinj)
- 8/22/2019: Removed [Stupid Web Tools](http://www.stupidwebtools.com/) (out of service)
- 12/10/2019: Added [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)
- 1/9/2020: Removed [SmartIP.io](https://smartip.io/) (out of service)
- 11/6/2020: Added [Abstract](https://www.abstractapi.com/)
- 11/13/2020: Added [AstroIP.co](https://astroip.co/)
- 4/13/2021: Replaced code samples with snippets (was getting close to 30k character limit)
- 4/13/2021: Added code to convert key-value pairs to JSON for plain text responses
- 4/13/2021: Added limitation "Requires non-null `Origin` request header"
- 4/13/2021: Added [BigDataCloud](https://www.bigdatacloud.com/ip-geolocation-apis)
- 4/13/2021: Reinstated [Snoopi.io](https://www.snoopi.io/)
- 4/13/2021: Removed [AstroIP.co](https://astroip.co/) (out of service)
- 4/13/2021: Removed [Nekudo](http://geoip.nekudo.com/) (now part of ipapi)

Comment: The ipify sample seems to be revised (jsonp and ? callback are not usually usefull!). Use this code is better: `await fetch("https://api.ipify.org?format=text").then(resp => resp.text())`

Comment: The Ablock plugin seems to block some of these, eg. `Cloudflare`, `GeoIPLookup.io`, `ipapi`, `ipdata`, `ipinfo.io`, `jsonip.com`.

Comment: another https://geolocation-db.com/json/

Answer (score 312):

### UPDATE 2021:

As shown recently by a new Github repository, [webrtc-ip](https://github.com/joeymalvinni/webrtc-ip), you can now leak a user's ***public*** IP address using WebRTC. Sadly, this leak does not work for private IPs, due to the gradual shift to mDNS (at least for WebRTC), completely explained [here](https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/). However, here's a working demo:

```js
getIPs().then(res => document.write(res.join('\n')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/joeymalvinni/webrtc-ip/dist/bundle.dev.js"></script>
```

The compiled source code for this repository can be found [here](https://github.com/joeymalvinni/webrtc-ip/blob/main/dist/bundle.dev.js).

---

(Previously) **Final Update**

This solution would not longer work because browsers are fixing webrtc leak: for more info on that read this other question: [RTCIceCandidate no longer returning IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755747/rtcicecandidate-no-longer-returning-ip)

---

**Update**: I always wanted to make a min/ uglified version of the code, so here is an ES6 Promise code:

```js
var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})

/*Usage example*/
findIP.then(ip => document.write('your ip: ', ip)).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

**Note:** This new minified code would return only single IP if you want all the IPs of the user( which might be more depending on his network), use the original code...

---

thanks to **WebRTC**, it is very easy to get local IP in WebRTC supported browsers( at least for now). I have modified the source code, reduced the lines, not making any stun requests since you only want Local IP, not the Public IP, the below code works in latest Firefox and Chrome, just run the snippet and check for yourself:

```js
function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  }
  pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    });
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop); // create offer and set local description
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}



var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.textContent = 'Your IPs are: '
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function addIP(ip) {
  console.log('got ip: ', ip);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = ip;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

findIP(addIP);
```

```html
<h1> Demo retrieving Client IP using WebRTC </h1>
```

what is happening here is, we are creating a dummy peer connection, and for the remote peer to contact us, we generally exchange ice candidates with each other. And reading the ice candidates( from local session description and onIceCandidateEvent) we can tell the IP of the user.

where I took code from --> [Source](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips)

Comment: I got "Error: RTCPeerConnection constructor passed invalid RTCConfiguration - malformed URI: undefined" in Firefox 26

Comment: @BeniBela updated code to work with firefox 26, checked in windows machine, can you check and confirm?

Comment: With this I can get my inner-net IP address, that's awesome!

Comment: Does not work with com.android.chrome on Samsung mobile devices - mac address is returned.

Comment: Warning: This doesn't show your public IP, just the local network one. You can't use it for detecting a users country, for instance, if they are on a LAN

Comment: @FloatingRock you can retrieve public IP as well, using STUN server (and configure it while creating the peer), then again, that would require you to maintain/ use a STUN server, bring server code into picture.

Comment: This is known as the WebRTC Leak. Should be fixed by all mayor browsers, but it's not. More information here: https://www.privacytools.io/webrtc.html Possibly related to the Tor-browser leaking your real-ip.

Comment: This shows my private address, not my public address.

Answer (score 174):

You can, relaying it via server side with JSONP

And while googling to find one, found it here on SO [Can I perform a DNS lookup (hostname to IP address) using client-side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript)

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=getip"></script>
```

> **Note :** The telize.com API has permanently [shut down as of November 15th, 2015](http://www.cambus.net/adventures-in-running-a-free-public-api/).

Comment: while I appreciate this snippet, I think loading a JavaScript text content and evaluating that through a function is a severe security risk. What if the content of the response changes and all 100+ people here that voted this answer up and possibly used that snippet end up invoking a function with possible insecure content. I would only use this if it were a JSON string.

Comment: `Error
 
Over Quota

This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later.`

Comment: This is not a good answer as it involves a server side request. The question clearly stated "pure javascript".

Comment: Micah, there is no way possible to get an ip address with pure javascript. I suggest you do some reading on NAT and how that works. You need a server to echo your internet IP address back to you

Comment: The service is now down.

Comment: @CyrilN. yes, the creator of the service shut it down because it was being abused by spam/malware. see his post: http://www.cambus.net/adventures-in-running-a-free-public-api/

Comment: http://www.stupidwebtools.com/api/my_ip.txt or http://www.stupidwebtools.com/api/my_ip.json or 
http://www.stupidwebtools.com/api/my_ip.xml

Comment: This internet-based script is permanently non-fonctional now. Removing the dead code, it makes this answer a "you can Google to find something" answer. So it's _not an answer_ anymore by Stack Overflow definition. Sorry @ChadGrant, but I suggest you delete it to give visibility to working answers.

Answer (score 113):

Most of the answers here "work around" the need for server-side code by... Hitting someone else's server. Which is a totally valid technique, unless you *actually do need* to get the IP address without hitting a server.

Traditionally this wasn't possible without some sort of a plugin (and even then, you'd likely get the *wrong* IP address if you were behind a NAT router), but with the advent of WebRTC it is actually possible to do this... *If* you're targeting [browsers that support WebRTC](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection) (currently: Firefox, Chrome and Opera).

**[Please read mido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript/32841164#32841164)** for details on how you can retrieve useful client IP addresses using WebRTC.

Comment: @oscar: that appears to be the same technique (JSONP-returned server-visible IP) that chad mentioned in his answer. Which doesn't match the OP's requirement of "no server-side code". But yes, that is one way to accomplish it if you ignore that requirement.

Comment: This answer outdated because of WebRTC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript

Comment: Updated, @Akam. You should [give mido some props](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript/32841164#32841164) for pointing this out a few months back (after YEARS of folks posting embarrassingly wrong answers that still required server support).

Comment: is WebRTC more widely supported now?!

Comment: According to that "CanIUse" link, it is, @BugWhisperer. Unless you need IE.

Answer (score 103):

## Look no further

Check out http://www.ipify.org/

According to them:

> - You can use it **without limit** (even if you're doing millions of requests per minute).
> - ipify is completely open source (check out the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rdegges/ipify-api)).

Here's a working JS example (instead of wondering why this answer has so few votes, try it yourself to see it in action):

```
<script>
function getIP(json) {
  alert("My public IP address is: " + json.ip);
}
</script>
<script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Too lazy to copy/paste? I like it. [**Here's a  demo**](http://jsbin.com/bajubacaju/edit?html,output)

Too lazy to click? `:O`

> **Note**: *Turn off Adblock Plus / uBlock & co before running the demo .. otherwise, it just won't work.*

I have *nothing* to do with the IPify team. I just think it's ridiculously cool that someone would provide such a service for the general good.

Comment: Best part is that this comes from "https" whereas my calls to http IP helpers would get blocked because they are "not secure".

Comment: hey, it's showing me the CORS error, what should I do?

Comment: @saberprashant are you using "HTTPS"?

Comment: @FloatingRock, no I am using HTTP

Comment: @Peppa same as literally any of the answers, here. CSP has to be enabled for that site if your server returns the CSP header.  Which it should.  Also, ipify gets to know what IPs use your website

Answer (score 100):

You can't.  You'd have to ask a server.

Comment: But it kinda does, right?  I mean, if the answer is just "no, you can't" then I would argue this is a more correct answer than the currently upvoted "here, use this random appspot app," which seems like a dangerous answer to be at the top of the list.

Comment: IMO This is the correct answer and should be accepted. The question specifically says "no server side code."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript

Comment: Could you please elaborate? All the answers suggest you make a request to another server, but how does that server gets the IP from request you make and why can't browser do it?

Comment: @matthewwithanm I couldn't agree more.  I was scrolling through all the answers to see if anyone had said exactly this - and was prepared to offer it as an answer myself.  All the highly upvoted answers, while informative, all answer a different question.  Quoting the question: "I need to somehow pull the client's IP address using pure JavaScript; no server side code, not even SSI."  This answer is, factually, the correct answer.  Browser-sandboxed Javascript cannot do this (regardless of NAT or proxies).  The question should be changed if one of the other answers is to be accepted.

Answer (score 82):

You can do an ajax call to hostip.info or a similar service...

```
function myIP() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");

    for (i=0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
        ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
        if ( ipAddress[0] == "IP" ) return ipAddress[1];
    }

    return false;
}
```

As a bonus, geolocalisation information is returned in the same call.

Comment: You can also get a JSON representation using http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php, then parse the JSON with the browser function, jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: is there any request limit on "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php" ? where can I see this api details

Comment: It returns the IP of the Network Firewall. not the actual client IP. Is there a way we can get the actual Client IP?

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 77):

> Try this

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    alert(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.ip);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBL3D/79/)

Comment: this works $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    alert(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");  but how do I store the value into a variable? it seems to disappear outside of this get request loop

Comment: For a list of all free IP lookup services, you can refer to my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: How do I send this function to return the value of the ip?

Answer (score 27):

You can use my service http://ipinfo.io for this, which will give you the client IP, hostname, geolocation information and network owner. Here's a simple example that logs the IP:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");
```

Here's a more detailed JSFiddle example that also prints out the full response information, so you can see all of the available details: http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/

Comment: To avoid the Mixed Content Policy issues, change `http://ipinfo.io` to `//ipinfo.io` or https

Comment: We want to use your service, do you have any discount offer for Stackoverflow users?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani we're free for up to 50k req/month, for 100k with a backlink - see https://ipinfo.io/contact/creditlink

Answer (score 22):

Include this code in your page : `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>`

more doc [here](http://l2.io)

Comment: There is some degree of spammy pop ups associated with l2.io
ref: https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/c7f6ecfdd2e7cfb0dbd5c0151fac6547dbbc521bf2a6cd58324d19922d4bec70?environmentId=100
allows embedding of links like in the sample
http://117.254.84.212:3000/getjs?nadipdata="{"url":"/ip.js?var=myip","host":"l2.io","referer":"http://website.com/?h=jn8bnnbgisbnnnhbn","categories":[0],"reputations":[1],"nadipdomain":1}"&screenheight=768&screenwidth=1366&tm=1557565256073&lib=true&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0

Answer (score 18):

There are two interpretations to this question.  Most folks interpreted "Client IP" to mean the Public IP Address that Web server's see outside the LAN and out on the Internet.  This is not the IP address of the client computer in most cases, though

I needed the real IP address of the computer that is running the browser that is hosting my JavaScript software (which is almost always a local IP address on a LAN that is behind something that NAT layer).

Mido posted a FANTASTIC answer, above, that seems to be the only answer that really provided the IP address of the client.

Thanks for that, Mido!

However, the function presented runs asynchronously.  I need to actually USE the IP address in my code, and with an asynchronous solution, I might try to use the IP address before it is retrieved/learned/stored.  I had to be able to wait on the results to arrive before using them.

Here is a "Waitable" version of Mido's function.  I hope it helps someone else:

```js
function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
            var pc = new myPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] }),
                noop = function () { },
                localIPs = {},
                ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
                key;
            function ipIterate(ip) {
                if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
                localIPs[ip] = true;
            }
            pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
            pc.createOffer(function (sdp) {
                sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
                    if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
                    line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
                });
                pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
            }, noop); // create offer and set local description

            pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) { //listen for candidate events
                if (ice && ice.candidate && ice.candidate.candidate && ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) {
                    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
                }
                resolve("FindIPsDone");
                return;
            };
        }
        catch (ex) {
            reject(Error(ex));
        }
    });// New Promise(...{ ... });
    return promise;
};

//This is the callback that gets run for each IP address found
function foundNewIP(ip) {
    if (typeof window.ipAddress === 'undefined')
    {
        window.ipAddress = ip;
    }
    else
    {
        window.ipAddress += " - " + ip;
    }
}

//This is How to use the Waitable findIP function, and react to the
//results arriving
var ipWaitObject = findIP(foundNewIP);        // Puts found IP(s) in window.ipAddress
ipWaitObject.then(
    function (result) {
        alert ("IP(s) Found.  Result: '" + result + "'. You can use them now: " + window.ipAddress)
    },
    function (err) {
        alert ("IP(s) NOT Found.  FAILED!  " + err)
    }
);
```

```html
<h1>Demo "Waitable" Client IP Retrieval using WebRTC </h1>
```

Answer (score 16):

I would say Chad and Malta has great answer. However, theirs are complicated. So I suggest this code that I found from ads by country plugin

```
<script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
mmjsCountryCode = geoip_country_code();
mmjsCountryName = geoip_country_name();

</script>
```

**No ajax. Just plain javascripts. :D**

If you go to http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js you will see that it contains

```
function geoip_country_code() { return 'ID'; }
function geoip_country_name() { return 'Indonesia'; }
function geoip_city()         { return 'Jakarta'; }
function geoip_region()       { return '04'; }
function geoip_region_name()  { return 'Jakarta Raya'; }
function geoip_latitude()     { return '-6.1744'; }
function geoip_longitude()    { return '106.8294'; }
function geoip_postal_code()  { return ''; }
function geoip_area_code()    { return ''; }
function geoip_metro_code()   { return ''; }
```

It doesn't really answer the question yet because

http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js doesn't contain the IP (although I bet it uses the IP to get the country).

But it's so easy to make a PhP script that pop something like

```
function visitorsIP()   { return '123.123.123.123'; }
```

Make that. Put on http://yourdomain.com/yourip.php.

Then do

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://yourdomain.com/yourip.php"></script>
```

The question specifically mention NOT to use third party script. There is no other way. Javascript cannot know your IP. But other servers that  can be accessed through javascript can which work just as well with no issue.

Comment: loading a JavaScript from a remote server and invoking functions with unknown contents seems like a huge security risk to me (what if the function contents change?). I'd rather prefer parsing a JSON response.

Comment: Error 404: Object not found

Comment: It's been a very long time., The answer is quite false actually. I didn't know javascript can't know the IP.

Comment: oh it's correct the function visitorsIP is not meant to be a php code. It's a javacript code generated by php code

Comment: you can just use your own server then to print a javascript code that assign visitors ip.

Answer (score 16):

First of all the ***actual answer***: **It is not possible to use purely client-side executed code to find out your own IP address.**

However, you can just do a GET request towards https://hutils.loxal.net/whois and receive something like this to obtain a client's IP address

```
{
  "ip": "88.217.152.15",
  "city": "Munich",
  "isp": "M-net Telekommunikations GmbH",
  "country": "Germany",
  "countryIso": "DE",
  "postalCode": "80469",
  "subdivisionIso": "BY",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "cityGeonameId": 2867714,
  "countryGeonameId": 2921044,
  "subdivisionGeonameId": 2951839,
  "ispId": 8767,
  "latitude": 48.1299,
  "longitude": 11.5732,
  "fingerprint": "61c5880ee234d66bded68be14c0f44236f024cc12efb6db56e4031795f5dc4c4",
  "session": "69c2c032a88fcd5e9d02d0dd6a5080e27d5aafc374a06e51a86fec101508dfd3",
  "fraud": 0.024,
  "tor": false
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Not possible in general unless you use some kind of external service.

Comment: Indeed, this is possible using Javascript by relying on a third-party service such as [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service): https://ipregistry.co/docs/getting-location-from-ip-address#javascript 

You can get the IP address, and much related information including threat data, all in a single call.

Answer (score 14):

Well, I am digressing from the question, but I had a similar need today and though I couldn't find the ID from the client using Javascript, I did the following.

On the server side: -

```
<div style="display:none;visibility:hidden" id="uip"><%= Request.UserHostAddress %></div>
```

Using Javascript

```
var ip = $get("uip").innerHTML;
```

I am using ASP.Net Ajax, but you can use getElementById instead of $get().

What's happening is, I've got a hidden div element on the page with the user's IP rendered from the server. Than in Javascript I just load that value.

This might be helpful to some people with a similar requirement like yours (like me while I hadn't figure this out).

Cheers!

Comment: -1: The OP specifically mentions "no server side code", yet you use some C#.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just output `<script>var uip='<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>';</script>`?

Comment: aside from using server side code, one should never use the DOM to store data. This is just bad all over. Hainesy has a better idea to just assign to JS var.

Answer (score 13):

With using Smart-IP.net [Geo-IP API](http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api). For example, by using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
        function(data){
            alert( data.host);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: "Service Temporary Unavailable".

Comment: wrote a simple api [https://geoip.immanuel.co/myip] to get client ip address, ssl enabled and no limit

Answer (score 13):

There's an easier and free approach that won't ask your visitor for any permission.

It consists in submitting a very simple Ajax POST request to http://freegeoip.net/json. Once you receive your location information, in JSON, you react accordingly by updating the page or redirecting to a new one.

Here is how you submit your request for location information:

```
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
     console.log(location)
  }
} );
```

Comment: It seems they have shutdown on July 1st 2018

Answer (score 11):

I really like [`api.ipify.org`](https://www.ipify.org/) because it supports both HTTP and HTTPS.

Here are some examples of getting the IP using `api.ipify.org` using jQuery.

#### JSON Format over HTTPS

```
https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
    alert(e.ip);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### JSON Format over HTTP

```
http://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

```js
$.getJSON("http://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
    alert(e.ip);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Text format over HTTPS

If you don't want it in JSON there is also a plaintext response over HTTPS

```
https://api.ipify.org
```

#### Text format over HTTP

And there is also a plaintext response over HTTP

```
http://api.ipify.org
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [userinfo.io](http://userinfo.io) javascript library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="userinfo.0.0.1.min.js"></script>

UserInfo.getInfo(function(data) {
  alert(data.ip_address);
}, function(err) {
  // Do something with the error
});
```

You can also use requirejs to load the script.

It will give you the IP address of your visitor, as well as a few data on its location (country, city, etc.). It is based on maxmind geoip database.

*Disclaimer: I wrote this library*

Answer (score 9):

**Get your IP with jQuery**

you can get your public IP address with one line of JS? There is a free service that offers this for you and a get request is all that you need to do:

```
   $.get('http://jsonip.com/', function(r){ console.log(r.ip); });
```

For the above snippet to work, your browser will have to support CORS (cross-origin request sharing). Otherwise
a security exception would be thrown. In older browsers, you can use this version, which uses a JSON-P request:

```
   $.getJSON('http://jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(r){ console.log(r.ip); });
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-391979&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow).

The API also provides geolocation data and has 10 global endpoints each able to handle >800M requests a day!

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-391979-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

```js
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function (response) {
    $("#response").html(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="response"></pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

There isn't really a reliable way to get the client computer's IP address.

This goes through some of the possibilities. The code that uses Java will break if the user has multiple interfaces.

http://nanoagent.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-find-evaluate-remoteaddrclients.html

From looking at the other answers here it sounds like you may want to get the client's public IP address, which is probably the address of the router they're using to connect to the internet. A lot of the other answers here talk about that. I would recommend creating and hosting your own server side page for receiving the request and responding with the IP address instead of depending on someone else's service that may or may not continue to work.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to offer a method that I use a lot when I want to store information in the html page, and want my javascript to read information without actually having to pass parameters to the javascript. This is especially useful when your script is referenced externally, rather than inline.

It doesn't meet the criterion of "no server side script", however. But if you can include server side scripting in your html, do this:

Make hidden label elements at the bottom of your html page, just above the end body tag.

Your label will look like this:

```
<label id="ip" class="hiddenlabel"><?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?></label>
```

Be sure to make a class called `hiddenlabel` and set the `visibility:hidden` so no one actually sees the label. You can store lots of things this way, in hidden labels.

Now, in your javascript, to retrieve the information stored in the label (in this case the client's ip address), you can do this:

```
var ip = document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML;
```

Now your variable "ip" equals the ip address. Now you can pass the ip to your API request.

*** EDIT 2 YEARS LATER ***
Two minor refinements:

I routinely use this method, but call the label `class="data"`, because, in fact, it is a way to store data. Class name "hiddenlabel" is kind of a stupid name.

The second modification is in the style sheet, instead of `visibility:hidden`:

```
.data{
    display:none;
}
```

...is the better way of doing it.

Comment: Don't store data in the DOM. Why would anyone suggest that, even 2 years later? If you can inject whatever into the HTML file, just inject that value into a JS variable like so. <script>var ip = <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?></script>. At least then screen readers will miss it and no getElementById or $('#stupidname') required.

Comment: @fractalspawn , For the reason that you can't insert php code into a .js file. Didn't think of THAT, did you smarty pants! ;)

Comment: Well, you could if you did <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/fancy/javascript.php"></script> though I'm not sure why you would do that either. My point is that if PHP can insert anything into the HTML that it's rendering, the best practice would be to have it insert a value into a JS variable within an inline script tag, rather than into a DOM element that you would then have to parse out in order to use, and could potentially be read by screen readers unless you took extra measures to prevent it.

Comment: There is absolutely no good reason why you can't or shouldn't add data holding elements to the DOM, and there are plenty of good reasons for doing it. In fact, those reasons are in my answer, if you would care to read it again. It is reliable, easy to control, and especially useful when your javascript file occurs on a remote site. Speaking of remote script, your example of "javascript.php" is a horrible idea, and probably wouldn't work, anyway. Think in terms of remote scripts, such as DISQUS.

Comment: Stumbled on this question, and I had to support @fractalspawn here : You shouldn't store data in the DOM. Actually his snippet `<script>var ip = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>';</script>` works flawlessly and you can access the `ip` variable in javascript without even needing to go through the dom with a getElementByID call. And as he said, it's much better for screen readers (or even text rendering browsers)

Comment: @ Benjamin C. - Again another reader completely misses the problem that a Javascript file, especially a remotely hosted Javascript library file DOES NOT PROCESS SERVER SIDE CODE. The suggestion to use "javascript.php" is an absurdly crude hack. Some people say data should not be stored in the DOM, not one of them has really explained why not. In fact that, TABLE elements are data storage elements, as well as LABEL elements. The method I described works especially well for remotely hosted scripts and html objects. Try to think your answer through before downvoting a better answer.

Comment: @Gregory Lewis: seems we both are not understanding each others points. I will just agree to disagree. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: @fractalspawn - If I was writing a .js script, it would instantly invalidate your suggestion. Nobody here has really explained why `<label><?php echo $_SERVER['remote_addr']; ?></label>` isn't a good idea.

Comment: The way I see the original problem is that we are trying to get the IP from the server. Assuming that the dev wants to use this information in JS code; putting it in the DOM then hiding it is redundant. Using the DOM to store arbitrary data from the server for use in JS code is what is not favorable here. If you only wanted to display it to the user then your answer is fine (hiding styles excluded). Additionally, PHP doesn't care what/who you are echoing to. It could be .jpg data, .js code or .css rules. IIRC, as long as the browser gets what it expects, the source and means are of no concern.

Comment: To your other comment about why DOM data storage is bad.. well, you can still stop a car by gently hitting a wall at your destination, but there are better tools for the job now. We now know better and have great frameworks to alleviate this. I worked at a place where the DOM was just a huge config file for the JS, and it was a nightmare when restyled. If you feel that using <script src="something.php"> is a "crude hack", but storing data in the DOM that only has value inside of Javascript is not, then I'm really glad that we don't work together and will again, gladly agree to disagree. :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm really glad I don't work with somebody who would consider writing a server side script like "javascript.php" as a reasonable solution to a client side scripting language, especially when we build script libraries that may reside on an altogether different domain :/ And I guess I'm still not seeing the disadvantage of using DOM elements to store data, especially in light of the fact that you don't always have the ability to write a "javascript.php" type javascript library.

Comment: @TARKUS He is putting that script in a html file... same as you do your label. Of course there is no good reason to put data in a html. Keep it simple in a js variable.

Comment: @Totty.js he's linking a php file, not a javascript file. What if it was cross domain? Has to be a .js file.

Comment: I mean this is better: `<script>var ip = <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?></script>` than putting `<label><?php echo $_SERVER['remote_addr']; ?></label>`. No need to parse html in the first one as it is simple js.

Comment: @Totty.js read the question again. You're making the assumption that it's about linking to a remote script. That's not in the question at all. The OP wants to access the remote IP. That's all.

Answer (score 8):

[Javascript / jQuery get Client's IP Address & Location](http://ip.codehelper.io) (Country, City)

You only need to embed a  tag with "src" link to the server. The server will return "codehelper_ip" as an Object / JSON, and you can use it right away.

```
// First, embed this script in your head or at bottom of the page.
<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
// You can use it
<script language="Javascript">
    alert(codehelper_ip.IP);
    alert(codehelper_ip.Country);
</script>
```

More information at [Javascript Detect Real IP Address Plus Country](http://ip.codehelper.io)

If you are using jQUery, you can try:

```
console.log(codehelper_ip);
```

It will show you more information about returned object.

If you want callback function, please try this:

```
// First, embed this script in your head or at bottom of the page.
<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?callback=yourcallback"></script>
// You can use it
<script language="Javascript">
    function yourcallback(json) {
       alert(json.IP);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: don't use `language` attribute, use `type="text/javascript"` instead, more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: as @Alex already mentioned, language is deprecated and is used only in legacy code. Use 'type="text/javascript"' for maximum compatibility instead.

Comment: just FYI - the type field is not needed for HTML5 (JS is the default).  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp

Comment: Just in case you missed these other comments, you should use type instead of language

Answer (score 8):

If you're including an file anways, you could do a simple ajax get:

```
function ip_callback() {
    $.get("ajax.getIp.php",function(data){ return data; }
}
```

And `ajax.getIp.php` would be this:

```
<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Appspot.com callback's service isn't available.  ipinfo.io seems to be working.

I did an extra step and retrieved all geo info using AngularJS. (Thanks to Ricardo)  Check it out.

```
<div ng-controller="geoCtrl">
  <p ng-bind="ip"></p>
  <p ng-bind="hostname"></p>
  <p ng-bind="loc"></p>
  <p ng-bind="org"></p>
  <p ng-bind="city"></p>
  <p ng-bind="region"></p>
  <p ng-bind="country"></p>
  <p ng-bind="phone"></p>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
'use strict';
var geo = angular.module('geo', [])
.controller('geoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.jsonp('http://ipinfo.io/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data) {
    $scope.ip = data.ip;
    $scope.hostname = data.hostname;
    $scope.loc = data.loc; //Latitude and Longitude
    $scope.org = data.org; //organization
    $scope.city = data.city;
    $scope.region = data.region; //state
    $scope.country = data.country;
    $scope.phone = data.phone; //city area code
  });
}]);
</script>
```

Working page here: http://www.orangecountyseomarketing.com/projects/_ip_angularjs.html

Answer (score 8):

Try this: http://httpbin.org/ip (or https://httpbin.org/ip)

Example with https:

```
$.getJSON('https://httpbin.org/ip', function(data) {
                console.log(data['origin']);
});
```

Source: http://httpbin.org/

Answer (score 7):

**Get System Local IP:**

```
  try {
var RTCPeerConnection = window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {
        rtc.createDataChannel('', { reliable: false });
    };

    rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
        if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);
    };
    rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
        grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
    }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });


    var addrs = Object.create(null);
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
    function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
        if (newAddr in addrs) return;
        else addrs[newAddr] = true;
        var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function (k) { return addrs[k]; });
        LgIpDynAdd = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
        alert(LgIpDynAdd)
    }

    function grepSDP(sdp) {
        var hosts = [];
        sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {
            if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[4],
                    type = parts[7];
                if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
            } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[2];
                alert(addr);
            }
        });
    }
})();} catch (ex) { }
```

Comment: Awesome. Great job. It would be nicer if you add some explanation or link of how it is working.

Answer (score 7):

If you use NGINX somewhere, you can add this snippet and ask your own server via any AJAX tool.

```
location /get_ip {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 $remote_addr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="getIp">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="getIpCtrl">
        <div ng-bind="ip"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript for load faster
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /// Scripts app

    'use strict';

    /* App Module */
    var getIp = angular.module('getIp', [ ]);

    getIp.controller('getIpCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http.jsonp('http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function(data) {
            $scope.ip = data.ip;
        });
      }]);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java Script to find IP**

*To get the IP Address I am making a JSON call to the Free Web Service*. like

[jsonip.com/json, ipinfo.io/json, www.telize.com/geoip, ip-api.com/json, api.hostip.info/get_json.php]

*and I am passing the name of the callback function which will be called on completion of the request.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
    var webService = "http://www.telize.com/geoip";
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = webService+"?callback=MyIP";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    };
    function MyIP(response) {
        document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + response.ip;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <span id = "ipaddress"></span>
    </form>
</body>
```

*for xml response [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript/5239085#5239085)*

*[WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript/25962226#25962226) which doesn't require server support.*