# JavaScript: How do I create JSONP?

Tags: php, javascript, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I have a two domains, example1.com and example2.com

From example1.com, I would like call a JSON API I have on example2.com. Knowing that this is not allowed, it occurred to me - this is exactly why JSON**P** was created.

Question is, how do I modify my JSON API to make it JSONP capable?

Basically, how do I create the callback api?

**UPDATE**

My server side language is PHP

Answer (score 77):

It is simple. Simply accept a parameter called `callback` in the GET.

Then wrap the callback JavaScript function around your data.

Example in PHP:

```
<?php

$data = '{}'; // json string

if(array_key_exists('callback', $_GET)){

    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com/');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    echo $callback.'('.$data.');';

}else{
    // normal JSON string
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

    echo $data;
}
```

It's idea is to simply return a JavaScript file which calls the callback function with the JSON object as the first parameter of the JavaScript callback function.

You can use the built-in `json_encode()` function to create JSON strings (which `$data` in our example above contains) from arrays and objects in PHP.

To use the JSONP service, you can use the `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
    function receiver(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
</script>
<script src="data-service.php?callback=receiver"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, is it really just that simply?

Comment: Do I need to add: echo 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
echo 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET'   ???

Comment: @Teddi: Those headers are to support the upcoming XMLHttpRequest 2 specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and BTW they already work on Firefox 3.5 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: @Mauris, would you mind updating your code to include the new XMLHttpRequest v2 spec headers. thanks

Comment: @Teddi - it's not that important because it's upcoming. It'll work with the script tag hack. Anyway I've added the headers in.

Comment: Please be sure to filter your callback parameter so only alpha, numeric, dot, and square brackets are valid characters. Otherwise you're stepping into a world of hurt.

Comment: @KentBrewster How would one do that?

Comment: @SnareChops, this is one way to clear out unwanted characters from the callback http://stackoverflow.com/a/10900911/1082542

Answer (score 26):

You need a server-side language, the callback parameter is simply a GET parameter, you read the param, and you wrap the JSON response into a function call and you print it like this `callback(jsonResponse);`.

I leave you a really minimalist example using Python since you don't mention any server-side language:

```
import os
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
callback = form.getvalue('callback','')

address = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])

json = '{"ip": "'+address+'", "address":"'+address+'"}'

#Allow cross domain XHR
print 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
print 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET'

if callback != '':
  print 'Content-Type: application/javascript'
  result = callback+'('+json+');'
else:
  print 'Content-Type: application/json'
  result = json

print ''
print result
```

That is the code of a small [JSONP service](http://zaa.ch/past/2009/7/3/crosssite_http_request_for_jsonip/) used to retrieve the client IP address made by [Zach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript/102681#102681) and it is hosted on the [Google App Engine](http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip).

Answer (score 6):

Mauris already gave you a working example. I would only add that you should check if a `callback` param is present and non-empty, and if not, return the json data as is without the parentheses. So basically your api will be JSON with provision of being JSON-P when `callback` is given.

To consume the JSON-P webservice, unless you use a framework like YUI or jQuery, you can simply create a script node dynamically and set its `src` attribute to point to the webservice. Remember to remove the node from the dom before repeating it again, since this dynamic script node is single use only.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to the party, and there was a comment about security of the code in one of the answers. Here is a good article about this:

http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/

And here is the code that you should be running:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

function is_valid_callback($subject)
{
    $identifier_syntax
      = '/^[$_\p{L}][$_\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\x{200C}\x{200D}]*+$/u';

    $reserved_words = array('break', 'do', 'instanceof', 'typeof', 'case',
      'else', 'new', 'var', 'catch', 'finally', 'return', 'void', 'continue', 
      'for', 'switch', 'while', 'debugger', 'function', 'this', 'with', 
      'default', 'if', 'throw', 'delete', 'in', 'try', 'class', 'enum', 
      'extends', 'super', 'const', 'export', 'import', 'implements', 'let', 
      'private', 'public', 'yield', 'interface', 'package', 'protected', 
      'static', 'null', 'true', 'false');

    return preg_match($identifier_syntax, $subject)
        && ! in_array(mb_strtolower($subject, 'UTF-8'), $reserved_words);
}

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$json = json_encode($data);

# JSON if no callback
if( ! isset($_GET['callback']))
    exit($json);

# JSONP if valid callback
if(is_valid_callback($_GET['callback']))
    exit("{$_GET['callback']}($json)");

# Otherwise, bad request
header('status: 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
```

Comment: If by chance anyone is using angular, this won't work. Angular supports jsonp, but replaces the callback with something like `angular.callback._0`. Would allowing a callback like this be unsafe?

Comment: @BobVork I don't believe so, you can change the `$identifier_syntax` to include periods as well. In fact, I believe I ended up doing that in my implementation for that very reason (but posted this before I had finished my implementation).

Answer (score 3):

```
// Adds script tag to head of the page
function addScriptToHead(source, code, type) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    if (type === 'js') {
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    }
    if (source !== '') {
        script.setAttribute('src', source);
    }
    if (code !== '') {
        if (document.all && !window.opera)  {
            script.text = code;
        } else {
            script.innerHTML = code;
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}


// Callback function
function addScriptToHead(any_param) {

// do whatever needs to be done

}

//call example

addScriptToHead('http://url_to_receiver_script/index.php&param=anything', '', 'js');
```

/// the callback script should return name of the Callback function, i.e. if you type in browser

http://url_to_receiver_script/index.php&param=anything

it should return just a text (name of existing processing function):   addScriptToHead(any_param)

works like a clock in any browser.

Answer (score 2):

Easy with jQuery,
that is the client side:

```
  $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: "somedata="+somevalue,
        //this is very important since it's the callback we will and that allow cross domain
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        url: 'http://example2.com',
        //function we trigger on success
        success: ParseJson
         //error handling not working with jsonP
         //error: handleError
        });

function ParseJson(data)
{
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + data[key]);
  }
}
}
```

And be sure that you get proper json from the server side; 
**and don't forget to return the jsonp_callback param, otherwise it won't work!!!!!**
and that's it really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) to forge it! It simplify everything!

```
<?php

  include('../includes/json.php');

  $json = new json('callback', 'myCallback');

  $object = new stdClass();
  $object->FirstName = 'John';
  $object->LastName = 'Doe';
  $array = array(1,'2', 'Pieter', true);
  $jsonOnly = '{"Hello" : "darling"}';
  // Add objects to send
  $json->add('status', '200');
  $json->add("worked");
  $json->add("things", false);
  $json->add('friend', $object);
  $json->add("arrays", $array);
  $json->add("json", $jsonOnly, false);

  /*
  Expected result : 
  myCallback({
    "status": "200",
    "worked": true,
    "things": false,
    "friend": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    },
    "arrays": [
        1,
        "2",
        "Pieter",
        true
    ],
    "json": {
        "Hello": "darling"
    }
  });

  */
  $json->send();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

example here
http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html
basically

```
<script src=".../example2...?output=json;callback=loadit"></script>
<script>
alert( "I got this from example2 " + loadit);
</script>
```