# Best way to sanitize callback for jsonp?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, callback, xss

What's the best way to sanitize the callback for jsonp?

I currently have something like:

```
function api_output($data) {

    if (isset($_GET['callback'])) {

        $cb = preg_replace("/[^][.\\'\\\"_A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $_GET['callback']);
        send_js_headers();
        print sprintf('%s(%s);', $cb, json_encode($data));
        exit(0);

    }

        send_json_headers();
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit(0);

}
```

Why? :

[Do I need to sanitize the callback parameter from a JSONP call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777021/do-i-need-to-sanitize-the-callback-parameter-from-a-jsonp-call)

Comment: Why do you try to sanitize the callback-parameter? If someone uses jsonp wrong it's his own fault.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to at all.  You're trying to prevent a client from XSS'ing itself??

Comment: Hi Carlos, can you be more clear about what you're trying to do, and quickly, before your question gets closed!? If it's what I think you're asking, I'm curious to see the answers. Good luck!

Comment: The function `api_output` should have two parameters instead of one. `$_GET` should be moved out of that function. But what exactly do you feel is in need of getting sanitized? And why?

Comment: The GET parameter was just there for clarity, this is a wrapper, our class is way more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback must be a valid javascript identifier, and your server side code should verify this. Javascript identifiers can only contain alphabets, numbers, underscore and $ symbol.

As long as the callback name is a valid JS identifier, you don't need to encode/escape it. And if the callback isn't a valid identifier, you should simply return a 400 error code.

You must NOT replace characters in the callback name. There just isn't any point in doing so, because the client code will no longer have the callback function defined.