# jQuery onsuccess not working even though firebug showing the response ok

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a problem in showing an alert box inside an onsuccess function called by $.ajax. I have checked firebug, and I do receive a response in json format but for some reason the the alert is coming neither am I able to console.log(jsonp). Below is the code:

```
$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ajax&destination=toronto&region=ca&avoid=tolls&sensor=false",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(jsonp) {
              alert(jsonp);
            console.log(jsonp);

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this is clearly written here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> By default, all requests are sent
> asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
> true by default). If you need
> synchronous requests, set this option
> to false. Cross-domain requests and
> dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
> support synchronous operation. Note
> that synchronous requests may
> temporarily lock the browser,
> disabling any actions while the
> request is active.

One more thing is mentioned

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using
> JSONP. Will add an extra "?callback=?"
> to the end of your URL to specify the
> callback.
>
> If you wish to force a crossDomain
> request (such as JSONP) on the same
> domain, set the value of crossDomain
> to true. This allows, for example,
> server-side redirection to another
> domain

Reference Links:

### [PHP-JSONP](http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/)

### [CROSS DOMAIN DATA with jsonp](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/)

### [JavaScript: How do I create JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678214/javascript-how-do-i-create-jsonp)

Comment: please explain what should i do when i am getting the response back from the server and i want to process that data which came back in json format but how can i access this data now ?

Comment: please read the link i provide...it is very easy..basically u have to write `?callback=` at the and of the url

Comment: now i am doing ?callback=myFunction but still inside myFunction i am not able to process the data no alert or log neither i can update any of Div id inside html using $(myDiv).text(jsonp_data); ? i will appreciate if you kindly mention the syntax

Comment: i update my answer with reference links.. please have a look..All D Best

Comment: Thanks i have read most of the links but still i am not able to print alert or use the data coming back from response. I can see the data is comming back in firbug. JsonP is working fine now how to use this data ?

Comment: sorry you are not understanding the question i am asking please understand the question first. I am getting the response back from googleapi and i see a JSON returned from the google but i am not able to alert or use its data in the call back funcction please tell me what i am missing do i have encode or decode json parse jason or some other thing to get the value out of that json came from google.

Comment: still unsuccessfull i dont know what am i missing. I do see JSON returned from google. in firebug , there must be some thing im missin.

Comment: did u try with only `alert()` .dont use 'console`

Comment: yes thats always the first thing. you can copy and paste it the above code and try at your end