# How can I echo text to a backend script with Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, backend

I have a PHP script which I want to output some text which I'm calling with AJAX to place in a textbox.  The text is generated with JavaScript but if I call `document.write()` then the whole page is refreshed and the text is displayed on its own - not in the textbox.

Here is the backend script:

```
<?php
  // unrelated stuff
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $toolsDirectory; ?>/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<?php if ($a = 2) { ?>
    <script src="someScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      var a = new A;
      document.write(a.go("<?php echo $testString; ?>"1));
      // -->
    </script>

<?php } ?>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm calling it with `$("#output").load("script.php");`.

I have also tried `$(body).html()` with the same result.

So just to sum up - the Javascript works, it outputs the right stuff.  If I just `echo "hello"` in the PHP, it loads it into the textbox as expected - it's just the Javascript writing that is confusing me.

Comment: NEVER use document.write after load. Instead load the result into a div

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but `if ($a = 2) {` assigns `2` to `$a`. In effect you have written `$a = 2; if (2) {`. Should use `==`.

Comment: That whole conditional was just an example.  I have a completely different condition in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A document can be in two states — open and closed.

While loading a document, it is open. Once it has finished loading, it is closed.

If you reopen a document, it wipes out everything in it.

If you try to write to a document, and it is in a closed state, then it automatically opens it.

This is what is happening to you.

Forget about `document.write` and [use DOM methods to modify the document](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/) instead.

Comment: Ok, I'm loading it directly from the backend script now, but it's not really the plan I had in mind.  I wanted it to be a bit more generic...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand why you're using javascript to echo content, when you're able to just use php...

```
<?php if ($a = 2) { ?>
    <script src="someScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php echo $testString; } ?>
```

edit: as you're passing it to a JS function, you'll have to use normal methods for changing content in the page... i.e.  give this a shot:

```
<?php if ($a = 2) { ?>
<div id="aresult"></div>
 <script src="someScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 var a = new A;
 $('#aresult').html(a.go('<?php echo $testString; ?>'));
 </script>
<?php } ?>
```

This way you're executing the javascript function normally, and putting the result somewhere on the page.  It can't just be echo'd in place as in the original code.

Comment: I'm passing the string into a javascript function which then outputs something different.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to this question:

[JavaScript: How do I create JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678214/javascript-how-do-i-create-jsonp/5435042#5435042)

The idea is - you make a call from JavaScript (client side) to a separate PHP script (server side). It generates some text and **returns the name of the callback JS function** with parameter (which can be your generated text). Callback JS function executes on client side and processes that parameter data.