# Programmatically call a firefox extension from javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have seen this excellent firefox extension, Screengrab!. It takes a "picture" of the web page and copies it to the clipboard or saves it to a png file. I need to do so, but with a new web page, from an url I have in javascript. I can open the web page in a new window, but then I have to call the extension -not to press the control- and saves the page once the page is fully loaded.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty certain that it is not possible to access *any* Firefox add-on through web page content.  This could create privacy and/or security issues within the Firefox browser (as the user has never given you permission to access such content on their machine).  For this reason, I believe Firefox add-ons run in an entirely different JavaScript context, thereby making this entirely impossible.

However, as Dmitriy's answer states, there are server-side workarounds that can be performed.

Comment: How about modifying the add-on to listen to some event that we can  dispatch from the web content?

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like ScreenGrab has any javascript API.

There is a [PHP solution for Saving Web Page as Image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/save-image-from-php-url-using-php)

If you need to do it from JavaScript (from client side) - you can:

**Step 1:** Create a PHP server app that does the trick (see the link), and that accepts JSONP call.

**Step 2:** Create a client side page (JavaScript) that will send a JSONP request to that PHP script. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678214/javascript-how-do-i-create-jsonp/5435042#5435042), that will help you to create such request.