# Need assistance with overcoming the cross domain issue, using node on the server side and JS on the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cross-domain

I am running an http server on port 8081, and am trying to get a JSON using the getJSON jQuery function. But am always running with cross domain (CORS) issue. I was thinking of using JSONP, but am not sure how am I am suppose implement it on my node.js script.

```
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type,X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER";
  headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = 86400;
  response.writeHead(200, headers);
  var objToJson = {"response":res };
  response.write(JSON.stringify(objToJson));
```

This is my client side code.

```
    jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost:8081', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? When working with CORS, I find that Chrome's console has the most helpful error log

Comment: This is the error message:- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt this PHP Script, the logic is very simple.
Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678243

```
if (array_key_exists('callback', $_GET)) {
    // JSONP String
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 0');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');

    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    echo $callback . '(' . $data . ');';
} else {
    // JSON String
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're doing wrong, but I copied your code, filled the blanks and it worked for me (on Firefox 16 and Chrome 24).

Here is my [CORS demo](https://gist.github.com/4059663):

- app.js

  ```
  var http = require('http');

  http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var headers = {};
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type,X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER";
    headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = 86400;

    response.writeHead(200, headers);
    var objToJson = {"response": "hello cors" };
    response.write(JSON.stringify(objToJson));
    response.end()
  }).listen(8081)
  ```
- index.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>CORS demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    view results in the console
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
      jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost:8081', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```