# Error: jQuery1830649454693285679_1359620502896 was not called JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parse-error

I have read through many, many Q&A of the same issue, but none have my specific issue (at least not that I could find).

I have a php script that echos back a json string

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $result;
```

JSON returned (checked with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) and is valid):

```
{"Announcement":{"ID":1,"Type":1,"Text":"This is a test Albums announcement.","TimeStart":"1969-12-31","TimeEnd":"1969-12-31"}}
```

And a web jquery script that reads the json:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://b***s.net/S****s/GetAnnouncements.php?callback=?",
        data : {get_param : "Announcement"},
        dataType : "json",
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown); alert(textStatus);},
        success : function(data) {alert('success');
            $.each(data, function(index, element) { alert('here');
                $("#announcements-list").append("<li><a id='announcements-a-" + element.ID + "' href='#announcement-details'><p>" + element.Type + ": " + element.Text + "</p></a></li>");
                $("#announcements-a-" + element.ID).bind('click', function() {Announcements.AnnouncementID = element.ID;});
            });
            $("#announcements-list").listview('refresh');
        }
    });
```

`success:` is never called. And `error:` returns a `textStatus` of `"parsererror"` and `errorThrown` is `"Error: jQuery1830649454693285679_1359620502896 was not called"`

- I have added `callback=?` to the url to work around the cross-domain issue.
- I have sent `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to the php, and it returns NO html.
- I have verified JSON validity with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com)
- I have tried removing the `data: "json"` as some answers say, but that still returns a `parsererror`
- Using jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: @salmanA Yes it should, and I feel embarassed... Though, that unfortunately did not change the outcome... :(

Comment: Just adding the `callback=?` doesn't automatically go around cross-domain issues... The server must return JSONP for it to work. (Otherwise it wouldn't be much of a security feature.)

Comment: @Juhana Now that it's been mentioned I knew what to search for and am adding the modifications to my php now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server and client scripts do not complement each other. You have two options:

---

Make your server side script return JSON:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{"Announcement":{"ID":1}}
```

And omit the callback parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://example.com/feed/json.php",
    dataType : "json"
});
```

---

Make your server side script return JSONP i.e. JSON wrapped in a callback function:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript

jQuery_xxxxxxxx({"Announcement":{"ID":1}});
```

And change datatype to jsonp:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://example.com/feed/json.php",
    dataType : "jsonp"
});
```

Note that jQuery silently appends `&callback=jQuery_xxxxxxxx` to the URL for such requests.
The server should use the callback name specified in the URL. You can do something like this:

```
echo sprintf(
    "%s(%s);",
    isset($_GET["callback"]) ? $_GET["callback"] : "void",
    json_encode($data)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I used the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678214/javascript-how-do-i-create-jsonp) (which is the same as yours) And it works beautifully now.

Answer (score 2):

I've just try and here is the solution tested in cross domain

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://******/14621356.php",
    data : {get_param : "Announcement"},
    dataType : "jsonp",
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown); alert(textStatus);},
    success : function(data) {alert('success');
        $.each(data, function(index, element) { alert('here');
            $("#announcements-list").append("<li><a id='announcements-a-" + element.ID + "' href='#announcement-details'><p>" + element.Type + ": " + element.Text + "</p></a></li>");
            $("#announcements-a-" + element.ID).bind('click', function() {Announcements.AnnouncementID = element.ID;});
        });
        $("#announcements-list").listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

And for the php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.'{"Announcement":{"ID":1,"Type":1,"Text":"This is a test Albums announcement.","TimeStart":"1969-12-31","TimeEnd":"1969-12-31"}}'.')';
```

Take care of jsonp in dataType.

Comment: It was the `echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $json . ");"` part that I was missing. I didn't know that you had to echo it back in a function. Thanks.