# Get hostname of client pc via javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an intranet app that needs to know where to print some labels. We have multiple workstations setup. I need a way to retrieve the host name of the client so that when they print something it comes out of the correct printer. Right now I have this being set at login but was curious if I could actually pull the host name on the client side, then on the server side i could easily parse the hostname to set the printer. The solves the problem of a user being logged into two workstations at once. Granted it shouldn't happen but users will be users.

The application is printing labels to a zebra printer so the printing occurs on the server but the print job is sent to the label printer that is next to the workstation being used.

TIA!

Comment: If it's an intranet, is IE required, or can you use whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the printing is done server-side, why do you need a JavaScript solution?

What you need is to check whatever is the equivalent to the REMOTE_HOST and/or REMOTE_ADDR CGI variables on your server's implementation.

**Edit**: in case you can't change the printing code, reverting to a separate script called through AJAX, as Andrew suggested, may be a way of getting what you want. But it looks like a very circuitous way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any reliable way to do what you're asking without using an external script and requesting it via Ajax.

See also: [Can I perform a DNS lookup (hostname to IP address) using client-side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript)

Edit: note, if you can it would be better (less HTTP requests) and easier to just include the host name in a dynamically generated `<script>` tag on the server-side before the page is loaded, that way the data is already there when you need it.

Comment: So I could put a little python script on their machine that would return the hostname but how would i call it from javascript? I didn't realize i could do that.

Comment: Calling the script from Javascript is reffered to as Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript and XML - ignore the XML part, it can be other formats too). You can do it a couple ways: make the script on your server return the client information via XML or Json or you could even make the server-side script print out Javascript and include it in your page as a `script` tag: `var client_hostname=...`

Comment: @Andrew Except the script is supposed to run on the *client*, not on the *server*. Unless you make every client into their own server.

Comment: @Zecc See the question I linked to. The general consensus there is that it can't be done with Javascript. Now if you made an Adobe Flash app or a custom Firefox extension, that is a different story.

Comment: I marked as answered to quickly as others have pointed out i needed it on the client side. I did see your answer further in the thread and will check it out.

Comment: @Ominus Fair enough. I should kept my mouth shut when I discovered a client side solution ;) I may write a blog post on it and include a compiled SWF and JS interface so you people don't need to learn Flex.

Comment: I deleted my other answer because after a good chunk of research I found out that getting the host client-side with Flash can only be done in Adobe Air which doesn't run in a browser or solve your problem. So it's back to square one... I don't think it is possible to do 100% client-side.