# How to get gethostbyname by using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, gethostbyname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I lookup the IP address of a hostname from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript)

Hi is there a jquery eqivalent to the php `gethostbyname()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you could make an ajax call to your server. The php on the server would then find it for you and return an answer. Note the following is untested.

Jquery

```
$.getJSON('gethostbyname.php', function(data){
    alert('Php said: ' +  data.ip);
});
```

**-- EDIT --**

Php

```
<?php
    $ip = gethostbyname('www.foo.com');
    $data.ip = $ip;
?>
```

If you wan't the domain to be dynamic you will have to use [JQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: What would you put in the 'gethostbyname.php' file

Comment: Do you have to encode to get json response?

Comment: Yes, json_encode($data); I think that would do it, I've never used getJSON though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `hostname` property of the `location` object in your JavaScript:

```
window.location.hostname
```