# Check if visitor is using a Android phone with HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Is there a way with HTML/Javascript to check if a visiter is using a Android phone, Sometimes I see this on Forums, when you open the forum on your Android phone it will have a popup saying that there is a app for that forum, how do people do this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009774/can-i-look-up-the-user-agent-from-javascript for general info on User Agent strings in JavaScript.

Comment: if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){ /* code for android */ }

Answer (score 3):

In theory, the following will work.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/ig)) {
    // Android only code
}
```

This is considered bad practice (UA Sniffing) though. Read [Browser Detection is Bad](http://c.nath.is/J1Oo). This shouldn't apply in your case though, as you're using it to look for a certain kind of device, not as a form of [feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection).

Answer (score 0):

When detecting Android user agents, read this post first: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-browser-user-agent-issues.html

In short, if an Android user agent does not also include the substring "Mobile", it is a tablet or other large-screen device and the user will probably be irritated with you if you serve them a phone-sized page. :)