# Can I retrieve an Internal IP address for a client using JS?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have to retrieve internal ip addresses(10.X.X.X) from clients on a intranet. The intranet is built using ASP.NET C# however i'd like to implement this feature in JS if possible. Can this be done in JS? If not how would i do this in ASP.NET?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicated question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: Doesn't look like you can get the internal IP address of the client unless the server is on the same internal network. Here is another duplicate candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript

Comment: I cant use PHP or JSON like both solutions suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...i'd like to implement this feature in JS if possible. Can this be done in JS?

[No.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

> If not how would i do this in ASP.NET?

Using [`UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this does give me the internal ip address.

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress should do the trick, on the server side.

Comment: This will give the external address, no?