# Obtaining IP address of server where the page is being hosted using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I lookup the IP address of a hostname from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript)

My page test.html is being hosted on server. Now, when I access the test.html from any computer, the test.html should simply display the IP address of server where the page is hosted, and not he IP address of requesting computer.

Is there any way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Cannot get ip using js alone.

Comment: @user: If you are going to view the ipaddress of the server. Then i think you can get that from the server and display it. But it's not possible through javascript.

Comment: @newfurniturey, thanks for your notice.Although, I didn't get exact answer, I got idea from there.