# make jquery snippet conditional to an IP

Tags: php, jquery

Is there a way to make this snippet fire off ONLY if my own IP is visiting the site?

```
        $('#preloader').delay(5555).fadeOut(1234,function(){  
           $(this).remove();
        });
```

Something like (pseudo-code): 
    "IF ip is NOT 127.0.0.1, do nothing."

(I'm open to a PHP solution if that would be easier.)

Thanks!

Comment: PHP - `echo $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]`

Comment: You could, of course, just paste that code into the browser console when you load the page. Or set it up as a grease monkey script or something like that if you want it automated. That way you wouldn't have to modify your main program source with test code (I assume that's what it is?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript cannot get the IP of the visitor, so a sever-side solution is the only one possible. Try this:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '1.1.1.1') { // your IP instead of 1.1.1.1 ?>
    $('#preloader').delay(5555).fadeOut(1234,function(){  
        $(this).remove();
    });
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this condition at PHP to show this part of code or not.

```
<? if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'): ?>
    $('#preloader').delay(5555).fadeOut(1234,function(){  
        $(this).remove();
    });
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the clientIP using both javascript and jquery.
You can, relaying it via server side with JSONP

And while googling to find one, found it here on SO [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript](http://zaa.ch/past/2009/7/3/crosssite_http_request_for_jsonip/)

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

also,jQuery can handle JSONP, just pass an url formatted with the callback=? paramtere to the $.getJSON method, for example:

```
 $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
       alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
  });
```

This example is of a really simple JSONP service implemented on Google App Engine, you can see more details [here](http://zaa.ch/past/2009/7/3/crosssite_http_request_for_jsonip/).

Check the source of the service, is a small Python script, it can be implemented on any server-side language.

If you aren't looking for a cross-domain solution the script can be simplified even more, since you don't need the callback parameter, and you return pure JSON.

Run the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ijiha/).