# How to find out wheres an ws:// window IP

Tags: javascript

I want to try get a IP of an server (website) in the browser

I tried the following:

```
function transmit_game_server_if_changed() {
    if (last_transmited_game_server != window.example.ws) {
        transmit_game_server()
    }
}

function transmit_game_server() {
    last_transmited_game_server = window.example.ws;
    socket.emit("cmd", {
        "name": "connect_server",
        "ip": last_transmited_game_server
}
```

`window.example.ws` doesn't work. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you need the IP for?

Comment: i need the IP so i can connect a sort of a bot with HTTP or socks4/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webbrowser APIs do [not include a way to perform DNS lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/102670/35070).

However, that's probably not what you want anyways - an IP can be used by multiple servers one or another, or a server could be reachable under multiple IPs (for instance IPv4 and IPv6). Instead, you can let the server generate a random value on startup, and hand that to the client. As soon as the client connects, it can determine whether it knows the server.