# Javascript: How can we get internal IP address without using any third party?

Tags: javascript, ip

I want to have the internal IP address of my LAN using simple javascript approach.

Without using any third party service.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no way to get your IP address with Javascript only**. You'll need to rely on a third party service (or retrieve your IP with on your server and return it in the view where your js code is printed).

> There's no notion of hosts or ip-addresses in the javascript standard library. So you'll have to access some external service to look up hostnames for you. I recommend hosting a cgi-bin which looks up the ip-address of a hostname and access that via javascript.

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-perform-a-dns-lookup-hostname-to-ip-address-using-client-side-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ONLY JavaScript and if it's not a problem to do that not browser-side only, you can use NodeJS and Express Framework to make a "micro-web app" which do something like :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var hey = request.connection.remoteAddress;
});
```

In addition, you can also retrieve a client IP even if it is behind a proxy with :

```
request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

[Interesting link on SO about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)

Maybe it's a bit overkill... Depending of what you wanna do.