# Can i get clients DNS IP address using JS?

Tags: javascript, server, dns, ip, connection-leaks

I am looking for a JS which gets users DNS Server IP.

Just like: dnsleak.com, ipleak.net

However, I know these are online services which can be used but i want something which can be run on my server and who ever visits that, I get his/her DNS Server IP.

Thank you.

Comment: No. you will never detect client's Ip address using javascript. You can use any third party api they will give ip address in response but it's not a feasible solution.

Comment: Search & read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-perform-a-dns-lookup-hostname-to-ip-address-using-client-side-javascript