# access request ip in javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript

https://jsbin.com/nabapojupu/edit?js,console

Snippet which it runs:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('GET', window.origin, true);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
      console.log(this);
  }
};
xhttp.send();
```

The image below is a screenshot of the above link with the browser network tab open; Highlighted is the IP of the domain requested..

Is it possible to access the request IP in JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I perform a DNS lookup (hostname to IP address) using client-side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-perform-a-dns-lookup-hostname-to-ip-address-using-client-side-javascript)

Comment: There's XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() that displays the header fully, but I have no idea if the remote IP is part of it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders

Comment: @TheMisir yes i think this answers my question. @fqrd that is good to know though thanks. My objective here was to attempt to detect if someone faking a website, ie using simple hack like `/etc/hosts` - seems like there is no 100% reliable way.

Comment: @John the standard solution to achieve this is HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG) doesn't specify any API for DNS name resolution, only Firefox implements [`browser.dns.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve) but this is very unlikely to become part of a standard specification.