# How to get IP address from domain name in browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, dns, ip

The goal is to plug in a domain name in the **browser** using Javascript and then to get out the IP address of that domain. For example, if I use https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/ to do it, I plug in `netflix.com` and I get IP address `3.211.157.115`.

I've been able to do this with Python code fairly easily using the socket library.

```
import socket
domain = "..."    
ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
```

How can I do this in the **browser** using Javascript, preferably without using any APIs?

Comment: are you asking for Browser JS or nodejs?

Comment: I'm using browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I perform a DNS lookup (hostname to IP address) using client-side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-perform-a-dns-lookup-hostname-to-ip-address-using-client-side-javascript)

Comment: There is nothing built into browser to do this. Would require an API. Make a request to your python server and do the ip lookup from there

Comment: I'm going to try and use my own Python server. Do you know which external API would be best if I end up using one?

Comment: What's wrong with the one you are using with your python? Searching for such API's should be easy using your favorite search engine

Comment: There's nothing wrong. It's just that I'm making a chrome extension and therefore cannot use Python, so I was trying to do it using Javascript

Comment: Look at DoH that standardizes DNS queries over HTTPS.