# Is it possible to prevent fake dns blocking (js fetch)

Tags: javascript, dns, fetch

I'm currently working on a website A that is using one of my apis on a website B.

The website A ask the website B some informations and I was thinking that if someone use a fake dns (or put the website B URL in his hosts file), it'll be impossible for my javascript code to get these informations.

Here's my question: is it possible to prevent it or not?

Comment: Use DNSSEC, this prevents DNS hijacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to prevent that, but not fully.

First, you could perform a dns lookup with javascript as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-perform-a-dns-lookup-hostname-to-ip-address-using-client-side-javascript).

As another option, you could just use the ip of your target server. But this isn't an ideal solution for production environments.

The third way that comes to mind is a proxy of your api via website A.

While all three of them are not very secure, keep in mind, that a potential user could also modify the client-side javascript code.

Also, welcome to StackOverflow!